# Shell script cut the specific line and specific field

Tags: shell, cut

```
echo "./Desktop/data.txt"| cut -f 1 -d ":"
```

The above line cuts the specific field with delimiter ":"

But how can i cut the specific line and specific field with delimiter ":" if my file consists of more than one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will simulate the `data.txt` file with

```
datatxt="Line 1 without colon
I want this:the part before the colon
nope, not me
other line with colon:that can be found"
```

Your command shows the first field of all lines

```
echo "${datatxt}" | cut -f 1 -d ":"
Line 1 without colon
I want this
nope, not me
other line with colon
```

You can get the lines with `:` when you use `grep` first:

```
echo "${datatxt}" | grep ":" | cut -f 1 -d ":"
I want this
other line with colon
```

You can append `| head -1` for one line output.
These instructions can be done with `sed` too.
With sed you can remove everything after the colon:

```
echo "${datatxt}" | sed 's/:.*//'
Line 1 without colon
I want this
nope, not me
other line with colon
```

In `sed` adding a grep can be done by looking for lines with `/:/`.
You should combine this with `-n` and `p`.

```
echo "${datatxt}" | sed -n '/:/ s/:.*//p'
I want this
other line with colon
```

When you want one line output, you can use

```
echo "${datatxt}" | sed -n '/:/ s/:.*//p' | sed -n '1p'
# OR SHORTER
echo "${datatxt}" | sed -n '/:/ {s/:.*//p;q}'
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a task ideal for AWK:

```
awk -F: 'NR == 2 {print $2}' "./Desktop/data.txt"
```

- `-F:` sets the field delimiter to `:`
- `NR == 2` is a pattern meaning "record (line) number is equal to 2"
- `{print $2}` is an action to execute on pattern match meaning "print second field"

Answer (score 2):

If you are choosing a line based on line number, then you can use sed.  For example, for line 10, do:

```
cat "./Desktop/data.txt"| cut -f 1 -d ":" | sed -n 10p
```

- -n tells sed to not print lines by default
- 10p tells sed when it gets to line 10, it should print.

If you need to choose a line based on that line containing a particular value in it, then I would use grep.  If the value is in a different column than the one you are cutting, then be sure to grep before you cut.

Note: the original post says echo "./Desktop/data.txt", and I'm assuming that was supposed to be cat, not echo.